# Jasmine test says module is not defined

Tags: javascript, jasmine, module-pattern

I'm experimenting with the following code...

```
// testable_scripts.js
function addition(){
  return 1 + 1;
}

// spec.js
describe('Addition', function(){
  it('Adds two numbers together', function(){
    expect(addition()).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

Everything works fine with the above code, but when I put the addition function inside a module and return it, I get "**ReferenceError: TestModule is not defined.**"

```
var TestModule = (function(){
  var addition = function(){
    return 1 + 1;
  };

  return {
    call_addition: function(){
      addition();
    }
  };
})();

// spec.js
describe('Addition', function(){
  it('Adds two numbers together', function(){
    expect(TestModule.call_addition()).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code TestModule have to be a function in order to return something:

try

```
var TestModule = function(){
  var addition = function(){
    return 1 + 1;
  };
  return {
    call_addition: function(){
      return addition();
    }
  };
};
// spec.js
describe('Addition', function(){
  it('Adds two numbers together', function(){
    expect(TestModule().call_addition()).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

Paste the above code in 
http://tryjasmine.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rahul. I edited my original question to use an IIFE. I had done this in my actual code but forgot to when posting the question (This is why I should fully wake up before asking questions in the morning). Your answer did solve my problem though; I needed to return addition() inside call_addition.

Comment: @DanielEmery can you accept it as an answer if it's resolved. Thanks.